# Can We have initializers in Enum in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I'm try to play with swift and enum. My concern is that Enum in swift is the Value data type. So can we have initializers in this like structure or class.

Comment: Did you really read this:- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html

Comment: Note that the docs link above doesn't actually cover enum initialisers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can:

```
enum Foo {
    case Bar, Qux

    init?(_ string: String) {
        switch string {
        case "Bar":
            self = .Bar
        case "Qux":
            self = .Qux
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }    
}

let foo = Foo("Bar")!

print(foo) // prints "Bar"
```

Comment: This is the way to do it (I'm using it to initialise a 'DayOfTheWeek' enum to today - useful!)